# Creating a random matrix with 7 rows by 21 column vectors with A,C,T G

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to coding and need to create a random matrix with 7 rows by 21 column vectors with A,C,T G as values.

Comment: `np.random.randint(1, 5, (7,21))` assuming you'd like them distributed normally

Comment: add some code to show what you already done

Comment: Your question(?) is pretty broad. If you search you'll probably find  enough Q&A's to get started making a list of lists.  Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service.   You should invest some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer for solving your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [412]: np.random.choice(list('ACTG'),(3,4),replace=True)                     
Out[412]: 
array([['C', 'C', 'C', 'G'],
       ['A', 'A', 'G', 'T'],
       ['G', 'A', 'T', 'T']], dtype='<U1')
```